Создать конструктор, который делает класс по generic
private T Create<T>()
    {
        return new T();
    {

мне нужно реализовать что то типо такого,чтобы на вход я передавал generic,а на выход получал конкретный экземпляр класса

Create<T>() => Create<T>() where T : new()

Сделайте ограничение типа
private T Create<T>() where T : new()

